# Convert cudaStream_t object to CUStream object

Tags: cuda, jcuda

Is there any way to convert `cudaStream_t` object to `CUStream`?

I found [this hack](https://forum.byte-welt.net/t/synchronizing-own-kernels-with-jcublas-calls/3771/4) but I don't think its safe to use. 
Or, is there any way to call `cudaLaunchKernel` in JCuda application using `cudaStream_t` object in CUDA 7.5 only?

Comment: As talonmies pointed out: In C, one can simply cast these types, but in JCuda, the conversion should be done via the appropriate constructors: `CUstream s = new CUstream(myCudaStream)` - in fact, this constructor was only introduced in response to the thread in the forum that you linked to, in order to avoid the hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a C level within the runtime and driver APIs,  `cudaStream_t` and `CUStream` are the [same type](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DRIVER.html#axzz4r20QtmaO) and can be used interchangeably in either API.

At a JCUDA level, it appears that `CUstream` has a [specialization](http://www.jcuda.org/jcuda/doc/jcuda/driver/CUstream.html) of its constructor for initializing an instance with an existing `cudaStream_t` instance. The provision of this alternative constructor eliminates the need for the pointer swap you linked to in the question.